# Payara ssl certificate and eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, payara

I have a problem for 2 days with eclipse console for payara that is not working anymore.
After I restart the server the only thing that is displayed is:

```
2018-08-25T05:28:01.959+0000|Info: Running Payara Version: Payara Server  4.1.2.174 #badassfish (build 192)
2018-08-25T05:28:01.961+0000|Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2018-08-25T05:28:02.587+0000|Info: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2018-08-25T05:28:02.594+0000|Info: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2018-08-25T05:28:02.599+0000|Info: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2018-08-25T05:28:02.694+0000|Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2018-08-25T05:28:02.776+0000|Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2018-08-25T05:28:02.809+0000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.31 started in: 86ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2018-08-25T05:28:02.937+0000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.31 started in: 24ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2018-08-25T05:28:02.954+0000|Info: Registered fish.payara.ha.hazelcast.store.HazelcastBackingStoreFactoryProxy for persistence-type = hazelcast in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2018-08-25T05:28:02.956+0000|Info: Registered Hazelcast BackingStoreFactory with persistence-type = hazelcast
2018-08-25T05:28:03.027+0000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.31 started in: 14ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2018-08-25T05:28:03.154+0000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.31 started in: 6ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2018-08-25T05:28:03.356+0000|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2018-08-25T05:28:03.364+0000|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2018-08-25T05:28:03.367+0000|Info: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2018-08-25T05:28:03.417+0000|Info: Created virtual server server
2018-08-25T05:28:03.421+0000|Info: Created virtual server __asadmin
2018-08-25T05:28:03.756+0000|Severe: The SSL certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 135786214035069526348186531221551781468391756233528066061569654028671100866720352830303278016129003918213826297308054231261658522889438712013757624116391437358730449661353175673177742307421061340003741057138887918110217006515773038453829253517076741780039735595086881329494037450587568122088113584549069375417
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sat Aug 22 16:41:51 GMT 1998,
               To: Wed Aug 22 16:41:51 GMT 2018]
  Issuer: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    35def4cf]
Certificate Extensions: 7
[1]: ObjectId: 1.2.840.113533.7.65.0 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 0D 30 0B 1B 05 56 33   2E 30 63 03 02 06 C0     ..0...V3.0c....
[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 48 E6 68 F9 2B D2 B2 95   D7 47 D8 23 20 10 4F 33  H.h.+....G.# .O3
0010: 98 90 9F D4                                        ....
]
]
[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]
[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [CN=CRL1, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US]
```

Despite the fact that Payara log (server.log) is populated after this with details, eclipse console not.
The used woraround was to use a tail -f server.log

PS: that happens to everybody in the office. So I guess it's something related with payara ssl expired certificate.
I'm using:
Payara Server 4.1.2.174 #badassfish (build 192) and Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) Build id: 20180405-1200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You can simply remove the failing certificate from the keystore. For me the failing certificate had alias: `equifaxsecureca` and was stored in `cacerts.jks`

I used the following command:

```
keytool.exe -delete -alias equifaxsecureca -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass <your pass>
```

BTW. There is also another one that is failing: `gtecybertrustglobalca`